# Hide env variable in production build (payload encryption and response decryption)

Tags: reactjs

I am a bit of confused about env variables in the production build. Simply i have a .env file which contains some variables like

```
REACT_APP_ALG=A128CBC-HS256
REACT_APP_K=RvIm6UTHG0wqXWLvkSmRqQhS97NvW_IwYw0CKYhEF_0
```

and accessing then in code like

```
        "alg": process.env.REACT_APP_ALG,
        "k": process.env.REACT_APP_K
```

But when I build my project then in bundle files i found some like

```
                    alg: "A128CBC-HS256",
                    k: "RvIm6UTHG0wqXWLvkSmRqQhS97NvW_IwYw0CKYhEF_0"
```

which is a security issue for me. Is there any way to hide them I'm well aware about that it's not a bug it's just I could not find any suitable solutions

Comment: You shouldn't use then the process variables directly:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838015/using-api-keys-in-a-react-app/46839021#46839021

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using API keys in a react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838015/using-api-keys-in-a-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several choices:

1 - Obfuscate/encode your data (but decryption will still be in your code...)

2 - Once logged, retrieve the data you need from the backend, before bootstrapping the application.

Comment: I have no other options cause I'm encrypting my payload so encryption key must be in the front end right ?? Just need a solution to make them unreadable

Comment: If browser can read it and send it, everyone can. First auth call should not be encrypted, then, retrieving encryption data upon auth, then you are secure